# Extra space with re.sub when wanting to remove mentions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, discord.py

```
async def on_message(self, message):
        attachmentimage = re.compile(r'(.(jpe?g|JPE?G|png|PNG))')
        attachmentgif = re.compile(r'(.(gif|GIF))')
        streamables = re.compile(r'streamable(\.com)\/([\w-]{2,50})')
        customemoji = re.compile(r'<:[\w]+:[\d]+>')
        animatedcustomemoji = re.compile(r'<a:[\w]+:[\d]+>')
        username = re.compile(r'@([A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:\'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]{2,32})')
        path = 'C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images/'
        words = re.sub(r'(@([A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:\'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]{2,32}))', '', message.clean_content)
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        if len(message.attachments) > 0 and attachmentimage.search(message.attachments[0].url) and message.channel.id == 423899570871861252:
            if message.mentions or customemoji.search(message.clean_content) or animatedcustomemoji.search(message.clean_content):
                print(re.sub(r'(<:|<a:|:[\d]+>)', '', words))
```

When I run it, there is an extra space with everything else next to it. I want to remove mentions completely but even though the `''` creates an extra space somehow.

Here is the output:

```
 hype
```

As you can see, it does remove the mention because of the:

```
re.sub(r'(@([A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:\'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]{2,32}))', '', message.clean_content)
```

But there is still a space before hype when there shouldn't be. How do I fix that?

Comment: Use strip() function of string to remove space before `hype`. At the end of re.sub use .strip()   `words = re.sub(r'(@([A-Za-z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:\'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]{2,32}))', '', message.clean_content).strip()`

Comment: Thanks, it works now.